# Shiny app with leaflet: uiOutput not showing up until goButton is pressed

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny app where a leaflet map animates through time, but you can pause it and then use a slider to look at specific years.  I've made a dummy version of the functionality and posted it here: 
https://seth127.shinyapps.io/slider

My issue is, the sliderInput to pick the year (which is inside renderUI in the server.R) doesn't appear until you've first clicked the goButton (which pauses the animation).  I can't seem to figure out why.

I want it to default to year 2000 (when input$animate==0).  I added a text input to verify that this functionality should work, and it works for the renderText, but not the renderUI.  Any help is much appreciated.  Code is below:

server.R

```
require(maps)
require(leaflet)
require(shiny)

fakeData <- data.frame(year=seq(1974,2014,by=1), 
                   lat=seq(34, 40, by=0.1463415),
                   long=seq(-118,-73, by=1.097561),
                   artist="fake",
                   album="fake",
                   hometown="fake",
                   chart="PJ")

pickYear <- function(year, data) {
    yearCities <- data[as.numeric(data$year)==year, ]
    yearCities
}

shinyServer(
function(input, output) {
    #refresh animation every 60 seconds
     getit <- reactive({
        invalidateLater(60000, session=NULL)
        Sys.time()
    })
    #change animation year every 2 seconds
    year <- reactive({
        if(input$animate %% 2 != 0) {
            invalidateLater(2000, session=NULL)
            1984 + (round(as.numeric(Sys.time() - getit())/2))
        } else {1984 + (round(as.numeric(Sys.time() - getit())/2))}

        })


output$pressedGo <- reactive({if(input$animate==0) {"you haven't pressed go"} else {"now you have"}})

output$reactiveSlider <- renderUI({
    yearVal <- if(input$animate == 0) {2000} else {year()}
    sliderInput('year', label='Pick A Year:', value = yearVal,
                min = 1984, max = 2015, step = 1, sep="")

})

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
            leaflet(data = pickYear(input$year, fakeData)) %>% addTiles() %>%
                addMarkers(~long, ~lat) %>% setView(-97.887318, 40.422487, 4) 
})

})
```

ui.R

```
require(maps)
require(leaflet)
require(shiny)

shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(
    # Application title
    headerPanel(
        ""
    ),
    sidebarPanel(

    ),
    mainPanel(
        uiOutput("reactiveSlider"),
        actionButton('animate', "Animate/Pause Map"),
        h3(textOutput("pressedGo")),
        p(" "),
        leafletOutput("map")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: pretty strange, seems there is some naming conflict.  If you rename `reactiveSlider` to something that doesnt start with 'r', it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an explanation of the issue, but a potential alternative - you can use the native functionality in shiny to do what you want:

```
sliderInput("animation", "Looping Animation:", 1984, 2015, 1, step = 1, 
                animate=animationOptions(interval=1, loop=T))
```

The key line here is the animation argument. See more examples here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html

Comment: Whoa!  That is way easier and cleaner than how I was doing it!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: This does solve my specific problem, but it still doesn't explain the weirdness with the actionButton.  I'm having a similar issue on a different app, so if anyone has any wisdom on that subject, I'd love to hear it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @seth127 I did track down the issue to the fact that Leaflet was depending on the slider via your pickyear function. If you comment out the leaflet ui call you'll notice the slider reappears. Might be a bug in leaflet, or a feature of shiny's lazy evaluation I'm not grokking